# How do I use a map of boost futures?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, future

I want to wait on a collection of futures.  When one becomes ready I want to look up an associated object.

I thought something like this would work

```
std::map<boost::shared_future<future_type>, MyObj*> futures;
//...
futures[future1] = my_obj_ptr1;
futures[future2] = my_obj_ptr2;
futures[future3] = my_obj_ptr3;
//...
std::map<boost::shared_future<future_type>, MyObj*>::iterator it;
it = boost::wait_for_any(futures.begin(), futures.end());
```

but I get errors like this:

error: 'struct std::pair, MyObj*>' has no member named 'future_'

Comment: `std::map` is a container of `std::pair`, which is certainly not waitable.

Answer (score 0):

It looks rather like you want to achieve something similar to win32 [WaitForMultipleObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which is not possible in *nix. Now with boost::thread implemented in C++11 some have wondered why something equivalent was not provided in the new threading model, the reason is its quite trivial to implement your own very quickly, depending on the strategy you want.

So you want to process the futures in ready order?

1) As each thread completes insert the future object into a mutex protected queue.

2) Then signal a condition variable in the waiting thread that a future is ready.

3) Waiting thread wakes-up and obtains the ready future and returns to the condition to await next signal.

4) Condition variable loop expires once all futures in the set have been processed.

That's it.